# Find all holomorphic functions with $\Re(f(x+iy))=2xy$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find all holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$
>
> $\Re(f(x+iy))=2xy$

So $f$ must be complex differentiable, which is equivalent to that Cauchy-Riemann equations must be satisfied

Let $f(x+iy)=P(x,y)+iQ(x,y)$ (Here $P(x,y)=2xy$)

then $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=2y=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}$

$\implies Q(x,y)=y^2+Q(x)$

the second equation is:

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=2x=-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$

$\implies Q(x)=-y^2$

Hence $Q(x,y)=x^2-y^2\implies f(x+iy)=2xy+i(x^2-y^2)$

Can you verify my steps, and holomorphic means differentiability in the complex sense right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is right, $f$ must be differentiable. But you missed some constants, we have - as you write (let me name the remaining function of $x$ $Q_1$ to see the difference to $Q$) - 
$$ Q(x,y) = y^2 + Q_1(x) $$
and 
$$ Q(x,y) = -x^2 + Q_2(y) $$
Equating both terms gives 
$$ y^2 + Q_1(x) = -x^2 + Q_2(y) \iff x^2 + Q_1(x) = y^2 - Q_2(y) $$
Note that the left hand side depends on $x$ only, the right hand side only on $y$, hence, both sides must be constant, say equal $c \in \mathbf R$. So 
$$ x^2 + Q_1(x) = c \iff Q_1(x) = c - x^2 \implies Q(x,y) = y^2-x^2 + c $$
Hence all functions 
$$ f(x+iy) = 2xy + i(y^2 - x^2) + ic, \quad c \in \mathbf R $$
are solutions to your problem.